# Spring MVC jsp return an item from a select

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I think I'm trying to do something very simple but I have been struggling!

Essentially I want to open a form with 1 select which is populated by a list of fairly simple items of type user.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id  private String userId; 
private String userName;
private String passwordCode;
private Date dateOfBirth;

    public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String get PasswordCode () {
    return passwordCode;
}

public Date getDateofBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
}
```

I want to return the selected item as SelectedUser via spring MVC as a modelAttribute.

So I am doing this in the Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController  extends JFrame { 

@Autowired private MeetingDAO meetingDAO;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String HomePage(@ModelAttribute("selectedUser") User selectedUser, Model model) {

    List<User> userlist = userDAO.ListAll();
    model.addAttribute("userlist ", userlist);

    return "Home";
}
```

Apologies to thise I have asked before as I have just realised I misunderstood the mechanism before.  Unfortunately now I understand better I'm still at a bit of a loss.  I want to have a list of type user and return the item selected as "selectedUser".

From what I can see I can't do this -

```
<form:form action="home" method="Post" modelAttribute="selectedUser" >
<form:select path="selectedUser" >
    <form:options items="${userlist}" itemValue="userId"  itemLabel="userName" />
</form:select>
```

as the path wants to set one property of User and won't set the object itself ?

If instead of Spring tags I do this -

```
<select id="userlist" name=Users onchange="changeFunc(value);">
    <c:forEach var="u" items="${userlist}" >
        <option value="${u}" >${u[1]} (ID:${u[0]})</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I can't see how I can assign the selected value into the "selectedUser" model attribute.

Is this possible or am I trying to do this the wrong way.  It seems like a very simple task that I can't get to grips with !  Possible I should just return the selected object in the request object ?  I was hoping to use the Spring mechanisms though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is something like this:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/select-user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String selectUser(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("usersList", userService.getAllUsers());
    model.addAttribute("selectedUser", new User());
    return "jspPageName";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/select-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String selectUserAction(@ModelAttribute("selectedUser") User selectedUser, Model model)
{
    // if you need only selected user id just use it
    System.out.println("Selected user: " + selectedUser.getUserId());

    // if you need whole user object take it from database using id
    selectedUser = userService.getUserByID(selectedUser.getUserId());
    System.out.println("Selected user: " + selectedUser);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

JSP form:

```
    <form:form method="post" commandName="selectedUser">
        <form:select path="userId">
             <form:options items="${usersList}" itemValue="userId" itemLabel="userName" />
        </form:select>
        <button class="btn btn-reg">SUBMIT</button>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Actually although this was very useful it also made me realise I've been looking in the wrong place for 1 - 2 days!  As I was filling the UserList from a stored proc not directly from hibernate it wasn't actually a list of Meeting objects after all but a list of comma separated values.  Ouch!